# Unable to send GET/POST request to server

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send get data to the server and read server message in response. The backend is in PHP and is working fine. But, whenever I am trying to send data from android, the `$_GET` or `$_POST` or `$_RESPONSE` array remains empty.

The doInBackground is :

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Inside do in background");

            try {

                Log.d(TAG,"Here is new url.");
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.33/post/home.php");

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


//sending data in json format

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                jsonObject.put("name","salman Khan");

                jsonObject.put("password","khankhan");

                String sendingString ;

                sendingString = jsonObject.toString();

                byte[] outputBytes = sendingString.getBytes("UTF-8");

                Log.d(TAG, "Output bytes are " + sendingString);

                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

                Log.d(TAG," got output stream.");
                outputStream.write(outputBytes);

                Log.d(TAG,"I am waiting for response code");
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                Log.d(TAG,"response code: " + responseCode);

                if ( responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                    String line;

                    Log.d(TAG,"Before reading the line.");

                    while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null )
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, " The line read is: " + line);
                    }
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

PHP code :

```
<?php

        $response = array();
        // print_r($_GET);
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        if ( !empty($_GET['name']) || !empty($_GET['password']))
        {
                // echo "I am in true.";
                $response['name'] = $_GET['name'];
                $response['password'] = $_GET['password'];
                $response['status'] = true;
        }
        else
        {
                $response['status'] = false;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

I am getting following log:

```
964 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan:  got output stream.
02-27 12:09:51.964 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan: I am waiting for response code
02-27 12:09:51.974 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan: response code: 200
02-27 12:09:51.974 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan: Before reading the line.
02-27 12:09:51.974 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan:  The line read is: Array
02-27 12:09:51.974 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan:  The line read is: (
02-27 12:09:51.974 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan:  The line read is: )
02-27 12:09:51.974 21872-21895/com.example.khan.post_interaction D/shahjahan:  The line read is: {"status":false}
```

Comment: If you're sending data via JSON and not as post fields, then it the data will not be in $_POST.  You have to read it from the stdin.

Comment: Basically I want to send in $_POST array. Please guide me for the same.

Comment: Don't know Android so I can't guide you on that.  But I can tell you that it looks like you're sending data as application/json.  If that's the case, then you need to read in the data properly in PHP or send the data differently.

Answer (score 1):

Check following permission added in manifes file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I have already added it. Application is communicating with server.

Answer (score 0):

Use volley ,the best way for transmitting data

`http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/volley/index.html`

In your Request class (that extends Request), override the getParams() method. You would do the same for headers, just override getHeaders().